# How to convert date in particular time zone

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Api response :

```
checkIn: "2021-08-30 03:45:00"

dstOffSet: 3600 
rawOffSet: -28800 
shortName: "PDT" 
timezone: "America/Los_Angeles" 
timezoneDisplayName: "Pacific Standard Time" 
timezoneId: 0 
zipCode: "94103"
```

I need to convert this `checkin` date in `America/Los_Angeles` time zone.

Any one please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: I think this is the same question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use `toLocaleString` like this:

```js
var result = new Date(new Date("2021-08-30 03:45:00")).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"}); 

console.log(result);
```